# How to use exponential smoothing for trading?

Tags: time-series, data, quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning

I was wondering if there's a rule of thumb regarding the value of alpha used when performing exponential smoothing. I plan to use this technique to preprocess my data before feeding them into my machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer given by Wikipedia:

> The time constant of an exponential moving average is the amount of
>   time for the smoothed response of a unit set function to reach
>   ${\displaystyle 1-1/e\approx 63.2\,\%}$ of the
>   original signal. The relationship between this time constant,
>   ${\displaystyle \tau } $ , and the smoothing factor, ${\displaystyle
> > \alpha }$, is given by the formula:
>
> ${\displaystyle \alpha =1-e^{-\Delta T \over \tau }}$
>
> Where ${\displaystyle \Delta T}$ is the sampling time interval
>   of the discrete time implementation. If the sampling time is fast
>   compared to the time constant then ${\displaystyle \alpha \ \approx {\frac{\Delta T}{\tau} }}$.

This canonical approach is fine, but I find it fairly inefficient because:

- taking the double and triple EMAs is redundant; it is essentially equal to using a lower alpha value;
- The weights of terms only converge to one; i.e., $\sum w \ne 1$; and
- Estimating initial parameters requires significant amount of recursion.

I therefore propose the following method: [Is there a non-recursive way of calculating the exponential moving average?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33548/is-there-a-non-recursive-way-of-calculating-the-exponential-moving-average/33635#33635)